# Gitlab: best approach for creating a manual production deployment pipeline

Tags: gitlab

I have a pipeline which builds and deploys my application to staging environment.
I want to create a job which can deploy my application to production environment, but it should be run manually.
In theory I see 2 options:

1. Create a separate *.deploy-to-prod.yml* pipeline with *when: manual* condition and run it via "play" button. As far as I understand its impossible because I cannot run an arbitrary pipeline in Gitlab, it always runs default one. **Please correct me if I am wrong.**
2. Hence only 2nd option is available for me: I need to create additional trigger job in my default .gitlab-ci.yml and add conditions: if execution is manual and some variable is set or environment = production - then run deploy to prod, otherwise a standard job should be executed.

An example of 2nd approach can look like:

```
manual-deploy-to-prod:
  stage: deploy
  trigger:
    include:
      - '.deploy-to-prod.yml'
    strategy: depend
  rules:
    - if: $MANUAL_DEPLOY_VERSION != null
      when: manual
```

..while in standard pipeline triggers I should add following lines to avoid execution along with production deployment:

```
rules:
    - if: $MANUAL_DEPLOY_VERSION == null
```

Is this a good approach?
Is it correct that only 2nd option is available for me?
What is the best practice for creating a manual production deployment pipeline?

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://bag.org.tr/proje/help/ci/pipelines.md#manually-executing-pipelines) does not allow you to define and run any pipeline through its play button?

Answer (score 0):

"Best" is a very subjective term, so it's difficult to tell you which one is best for your use-case. Insteaad, let me lay out a couple of options for how you could achieve what you're attempting to do:

1. You could update your deploy process to use `deploy.yml`, then use the `trigger` keyword in your CI file to trigger that job for different environments. You can then use the `rules` keyword to control when and how different jobs are triggered. This has the benefit of re-using your deployment process that you're using for your staging environment, which is nice and DRY and ensures that your deployment is repeatable across environments. This would look like this:

```yaml
deploy-to-staging:
  stage: deploy
  trigger: 
    include: deploy.yml
    strategy: depend
  when: on_success

deploy-to-production:
  stage: deploy
  trigger:
    include: deploy.yml
    strategy: depend
  when: manual
```

2. You could use the `rules` keyword to include your deploy-to-production job only when the job is kicked off manually from the UI. The rest of your pipeline would still execute (unless you explicitly tell it not to), but your deploy-to-prod job would only show up if you manually kicked the pipeline off. This would look like this:

```yaml
deploy-to-prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "I'm deploying!"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
      when: on_success
    - when: never
```

3. You could use a separate project for your deployment pipeline. This pipeline can retrieve artifacts from your other project, but would only run its CI when you manually click on run for that project. This gives you really nice separation of concerns because you can give a separate set of permissions to that project as opposed to the code project, and it can help keep your pipeline clean if it's really complicated.

All approaches have pros and cons, simply pick the one that works best for you!

Comment: Patrick, thanks a lot! 
Before I thought rules conditions are joined with AND clause. Which means having when: never makes your job from example 2 always off. Is this wrong?

Comment: @MiamiBeach - rules conditions are evaluated until the first rule evaluates to `true`. In my second example, that means the CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE evaluates to `true` when kicked off from the web, and applies the `on_success` rule. When kicked off from a commit, the source is != `web`, so it falls through to the second criteria, which is _always_ true since it has no `if` criteria, and sets the `when: never`.